# Tomcat with two NIC | One for External Users | Other for connecting With DB

Tags: tomcat, networking, multiple-interface-implem

I have many application deployed on linux machine with tomcat. Currently it is running on single IP, now I need to setup two different NIC (Network Interface Card).

One NIC for only external users to connect to my application
Second NIC only for my application for the connection with DB.

Kindly help how to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you provided, i can only punt you to the sample configuration like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/513805/properly-configure-two-eth-interfaces-on-different-subnets) and having [multiple NICs](http://coderazzi.net/linux/dual_nic_linux.htm).